# Understanding GitHub API response for a single release to find download statistics

Tags: api, github

The GitHub API [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release) on release information says:

> Information about published releases are available to everyone.

Thus, I considered it should be enough to be logged in GitHub, but not being member of a project to explore its download statistics for example (this is my use case).

Though, [this API call](https://api.github.com/repos/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/latest) for the latest release gives me an empty `assets` segment while there are release assets available.

```
  "assets": [

  ],
```

I've tested it with [another repo](https://api.github.com/repos/dropwizard/dropwizard/releases/latest) like Dropwizard and get same result - empty `assets`.

One test more - I have created a fake release in a repo of my own and tested the API on it, still same result.

How to access the data?

UPD how did I sent the API call?

- just through Chrome browser
- through curl 7.58.0: `curl https://api.github.com/repos/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/latest`

Comment: That's just because those repo have no assets, the html persentation is not clear but the source code zip and tarball are not assets. See for exemple https://api.github.com/repos/firehol/netdata/releases/latest which really have assets in its release

Comment: @Tensibai hi - updated the question. Both curl and browser.

Comment: @Tensibai this seems to be the right answer! thanks. Makes of course sense but was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

I visited https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases, There is no assets at all. Assets are attached when you [release your software](https://blog.github.com/2013-07-02-release-your-software/). @Tensibai is right.

Comment: I tried edit an existing release without assets, and attatched a binary file as asset. Then make a request,  it works, The `assets` property is no longer empty but populated with the info of the binary file.